# Box api Artdarek oauth 2.0 how to delete/post method

Tags: curl, methods, oauth, box

I need some help on how to do the delete/post method on artdarek oauth 2.0.

Since this is the GET method example (this is working):

```
$boxService = OAuth::consumer('Box');
$get_rootfolder_items = json_decode($boxService->request('/folders/0/items'), true);
```

but I want to do the DELETE method, here is my code

```
$boxService = OAuth::consumer('Box');
$delete_rootfolder = json_decode($boxService->delete('folders/'.$id.'?recursive=true'), true);
```

but returns the following error:

```
Call to undefined method OAuth\OAuth2\Service\Box::delete()
```

because box api uses the cURL here is their METHOD:

```
DELETE /folders/{folder id}
```

their example request:

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/FOLDER_ID?recursive=true  \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" \
-X DELETE
```

I really need help.

Answer (score 0):

For using a different method than `GET` in the request use the 2nd parameter to the `request` method, so:

```
$get_rootfolder_items = json_decode($boxService->request('folders/'.$id.'?recursive=true', 'DELETE'), true);
```